# "not in" comparison not working as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, string-comparison

I am having trouble with the `not in` comparison operator in Python 2.7. I have a list of US state abbreviations, and I want to check if a given abbreviation is not in that list, so I use:

```
'IL' not in states['Abbreviation']
```

Unexpectedly, I got a True; however, when I do the following, I also get a true.

```
'IL' == states['Abbreviation'][13]
```

`'IL'` is the 14th item on the list of abbreviations, and when I use `==` I can prove that it is in the list; however, when I use the `not in` comparison, it doesn't see it in the list? What gives?

I am a little new to python, so hopefully the answer isn't too embarrassing.

Thanks,

Michael

EDIT: And yes, I did my best to 'google' an answer before posting, but searching Google for the terms 'not in' is a futile endeavor, and the behavior I described above does not seem to be consistent with how the comparison is said to work in the documentation.

EDIT2: The list

```
in[89]: states['Abbreviation']

out[89]:

0     AL
1     AK
2     AZ
3     AR
4     CA
5     CO
6     CT
7     DE
8     DC
9     FL
10    GA
11    HI
12    ID
13    IL
14    IN
15    IA
16    KS
17    KY
18    LA
19    ME
20    MT
21    NE
22    NV
23    NH
24    NJ
25    NM
26    NY
27    NC
28    ND
29    OH
30    OK
31    OR
32    MD
33    MA
34    MI
35    MN
36    MS
37    MO
38    PA
39    RI
40    SC
41    SD
42    TN
43    TX
44    UT
45    VT
46    VA
47    WA
48    WV
49    WI
50    WY
Name: Abbreviation, dtype: object
```

EDIT3:

I defined the list using pandas in iPython notebook

```
import pandas as pd
states = pd.read_table('states.csv', sep=',')
```

states.csv is a file contain the state name in the first column, and the abbreviation in the second. That's pretty much all of it. What confused me is why is could use the `==` in one line to show it was in the list, and then not have `not in` give the right answer?

EDIT4:

As requested by a reply,

```
In [92]: type(states['Abbreviation'])
Out[92]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: show us your `states['Abbreviation']`

Comment: Show complete, executable code, so that other people can reproduce the behavior you claim.  The answer to this one depends on something you _haven't_ shown us.

Comment: If `states['Abbreviation']` is a list of the abbreviations, and if it includes 'IL', then the `not in` operation should have returned `False`.  There must be something more that you haven't shown.  You may have mistyped something and corrected it in your post.  Try to reproduce the problem, and if it happens again, include the definition of `states['Abbreviation']`.

Comment: Ok, so where are all those numbers coming from?  Try this:  `type(states['Abbreviation'])` to see what it *really* is.  It doesn't look like a list.

Comment: Ok, as suspected it wasn't a Python list at all.  That's why `not in` didn't do what you expected.

Comment: I want to thank you for all your effort (e.g. Tom for that in depth sample). Yes, definitely my fault for the loose usage of the term "list".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your `states` is not a list, but a pandas DataFrame, and `states['Abbreviation']` is one of its columns (a pandas Series).  Using `in` on a Series checks whether the value is in the index, not the values.  Try `'IL' in states['Abbreviation'].values`.

Comment: Okay, that worked. Really sorry about how simple it was. Was banging my head against a wall because of that inconsistent result. Thanks for the help.